# How to write random matrix using loops and without numpy

Tags: python

How can I create two matrixes **without** `numpy` as `A` and `B`(can also do these **operations**)?

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randint(-9, 9, size=(5, 5))
B = np.random.randint(-9, 9, size=(5, 5))

for i in range(5):
    print(A[i])
print()
for i in range(5):
    print(B[i])
print()
C = A * 2
for i in range(5):
    print(C[i])

result = [[A[j][i] for j in range(len(A))] for i in range(len(A[0]))]
print()
for r in result:
    print(r)
E = A + B
print()
for i in range(5):
    print(E[i])
F = A * B
print()
for i in range(5):
    print(B[i])
```

I tried like so, but in this case **[C=A*2]** gives me not multiply otherwise it writes 2 times matrix

```py
import random
A = []
size_x, size_y = 5, 5
for _ in range(size_y):
    row = []
    for _ in range(size_x):
        row.append(random.randint(-9, 9))
    A.append(row)

B = []
size_x, size_y = 5, 5
for _ in range(size_y):
    row = []
    for _ in range(size_x):
        row.append(random.randint(-9, 9))
    B.append(row)
```

Comment: You have already done what your title said.  You have created two random matrices without numpy.  HOWEVER, the whole-matrix operations you are talking about (like `C = A*2`) are strictly numpy operations.  Python doesn't have math operators for lists.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the answer. Is there any another way to do these operations just with python or is it imposible without numpy?

Comment: There is no need for numpy, what's the problem ?

Comment: @YağızArasan you can implement these matrix methods yourself, for matrices A and B their product C can be computed element-wise as c_ij = sum(a_ik * b_kj) for all k

Comment: @YvesDaoust i want to do operations like these, but i got diffrent results 
```
C = A * 2
E = A + B
F = A * B
```

Comment: Yes, you need numpy if you want to write matrix arithmetic using that notation.  @YvesDaoust is wrong.  You can surely write the matrix multiply routines on your own, but that would be silly.  numpy does it well, and is in wide use.

Comment: @TimRoberts: impossible without numpy ? Really ?

Comment: @Stanley TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Comment: @YvesDaoust Please feel free to post a practical solution that does not involve reinventing numpy's custom classes.

Comment: @YağızArasan -- Right.  What you have in `A` and `B` are lists.  Python does not define arithmetic operations for lists.  With `numpy`, `A` and `B` are numpy arrays. `numpy` DOES define arithmetic operations for its arrays.  It's just that simple.

Comment: @TimRoberts: the question is specifically how to avoid numpy. So "you need numpy" is irrelevant. A matrix addition or product takes three lines.

Comment: I will wager real dollars that the question he is asking is not the question he needs an answer to.